# What is the difference between bcl and expr?

Tags: scripting, math, expr

I know that both of them can do simple arithmetic. I'm wondering when it will be easier to use one versus the other.

I know that expr evaluates an expression from its arguments, while bcl evaluates from standard in, but what other differences are there?

Specifically, are there any tasks that one can perform, but the other can't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Specifically, are there any tasks that one can perform, but the other can't?

For one thing, `bc` supports big numbers while `expr` tops out at 2^63-1:

```
$ expr 9223372036854775807 + 1
-9223372036854775807

$ echo "9223372036854775807 + 1" | bc
9223372036854775808
```

`bc` also has exponentiation and square root operations, which `expr` lacks entirely:

```
$ echo "2^1024" | bc
17976931348623159077293051907890247336179769789423065727343008115773\
26758055009631327084773224075360211201138798713933576587897688144166\
22492847430639474124377767893424865485276302219601246094119453082952\
08500576883815068234246288147391311054082723716335051068458629823994\
7245938479716304835356329624224137216
$ echo "scale=100; sqrt(2)" | bc
1.414213562373095048801688724209698078569671875376948073176679737990\
7324784621070388503875343276415727
```